# Creating Android database journal file with SQLite browser

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm creating a database file with [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) in order to have better visibility of my database structure and create the databases for my apps faster.  However, I know that SQL on Android creates a journal file for rolling back on if a process has been interrupted.  If I use the database file I've created, will Android produce a journal file for my database once my app is run or will I have to create it through other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SQLite documentation at https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html
journal files are created on an as-needed basis.